# create container from another container, applying each element some function in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, containers, stl-algorithm

My question is simple, see example:

```
std::array<int,6> a = {{0,1,2,3,4,5}}; // -- given container.
auto F = []( int i ) { return  i*i; }; // -- given function.

std::vector<int> v;  // need create

// my solution:
v.reserve( a.size () );
for( std::size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i )
    v.push_back( F(a[i]) ); 



// but I need something like
   std::vector<int>v( a.begin(), a.end(), <|applying each element to F|> );
```

**Can I create container something like above not calling reserve explicitly and any reallocation?**

**EDIT**:

1. I want avoid reserve; because othercase my first solution is good
   for me :)
2. I want avoid any resize; because it's initialzed each
   element by default ctor.
3. I will use this in the real project which may included many 3-rd party libraries ( boost, Soft-STL, ...).

Comment: Will `std::transform` not do this?

Comment: [`transform iterators`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) might be of use here.

Comment: I want avoid v.reserve(a.size()), also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is to use [`boost::transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html). The benefit is that you can pass iterators to the container constructor. That avoids memory reallocations compared to when using `std::back_inserter` or having to call `reserve` or `resize` on the destination. All in one statement:

```
std::vector<int> result(
      boost::make_transform_iterator(std::begin(a), F)
    , boost::make_transform_iterator(std::end(a), F)
    );
```

---

You can achieve terser syntax though, like this:

```
std::vector<int> result(transform_range(a, F));
```

`transform_range` implementation:

```
template<class Iterator>
struct AutoSequence
{
    Iterator const beg_, end_;

    template<class T>
    operator std::vector<T>() const {
        return {beg_, end_};
    }
};

template<class Function, class InSeq>
auto transform_range(InSeq const& in) -> AutoSequence<decltype(boost::make_transform_iterator<Function>(in.begin()))> {
    return {
          boost::make_transform_iterator<Function>(std::begin(in))
        , boost::make_transform_iterator<Function>(std::end(in))
        };
}

template<class Function, class InSeq>
auto transform_range(InSeq const& in, Function&& f) -> AutoSequence<decltype(boost::make_transform_iterator(in.begin(), f))> {
    return {
          boost::make_transform_iterator(std::begin(in), f)
        , boost::make_transform_iterator(std::end(in), f)
        };
}
```

Comment: Completely unnecessary use of third-party library. What does this give you? One line of code saved here, a thousand added in a header. Awesome.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Cry me a river.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I mentioned the benefits in sentences 2 and 3.

Comment: so, did you measure that performance benefit? and also did you measure compilation time impact?

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: You failed to explain why it's a benefit, especially in contrast with the possible downsides of bringing in a 3rd-party library in just for this. A simple `reserve` is idiomatic, canonical, lightweight, easy, cheap and widely understood.

Comment: @Abyx By definition it is faster than using `back_inserter` because `back_inserter` is going to increment the size counter of the destination `N` times. Resizing would unnecessary initialize the elements to the default values. In other words, there is no faster version than passing the iterators to the constructor.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: Aha! A rationale! It's a sound one, too, though you'd still have to try very hard to convince me that this tiny micro-optimisation is worth bringing in a third-party library to do the job. Your answer, unfortunately, doesn't make the OP aware of this whatsoever.

Comment: @maxim-yegorushkin: Thanks, exactly that what I want.

Comment: #define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE  need with lambda )

Comment: @Abyx Regarding compilation times I agree that boost headers are quite heavy. However, programmer's time is most expensive, and time spent writing one's own version instead of using a free 3rd-party library may be economically unreasonable. Especially if using the 3rd-party library yields same or better performance and, most importantly, allows for more elegant code. The mathematical definition of elegance is simplicity and power and this is what we achieve here, do more with less.

Comment: @Khurshid Yeah, I hit it too. Not sure why boost does not detect this automatically.

Answer (score 12):

The standard algorithm [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) does *exactly* this!

```
std::vector<int> v(a.size());
std::transform(
   std::begin(a), std::end(a),
   std::begin(v),
   F
);
```

You can start with an empty vector and use [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter), if you like:

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::transform(
   std::begin(a), std::end(a),
   std::back_inserter(v),
   F
);
```

But you're subjecting yourself to needless re-allocations if you do that (unless you `reserve` first, as in your original attempt). You can decide for yourself what your priority is.

Comment: I can't use  v(a.size() ), because my real container element is not an int, some large class. and it's required me two lines.

Comment: @Khurshid: Sure, that's up to you. You have all options open to you here. What do you mean by requiring only two lines? Why? Space in source code is very cheap! :)

Comment: @Khurshid Still, a call to `reserve` + the `bqck_inserter` example seems like a fine option.

Comment: does back_inserter   call push_back ? if yes, it's not efficient memory usafe.

Comment: @Khurshid: Yes, which I addressed in my final paragraph. You can avoid that with `reserve`, as you already know, which I would recommend.

Comment: Seed Edit, I explain what I was want.

Comment: @Khurshid: `I want avoid reserve; because othercase my first solution is good for me`  That doesn't really make any sense, I'm afraid. All of these solutions are [more or less] equivalent in what they do: the only reason to prefer one over the other is _style_. So if you were unsatisfied with the style of your original approach, finding out that you still need a call to `reserve` is not going to change that. There is nothing ugly about a call to `reserve`, though: just do it and move on. :)

Comment: I was want, more readability solution without any cost to performance. explicit writing reserve - isn't readable, only for performance.

Comment: Here is first solution  calls default ctor, second's resized capacity every time.

Comment: @Khurshid: `reserve` is very readable. I grant you, since it is "just for perfomance" in a sense, it is an abstraction leak if you want your program to _just_ detail behaviours and not implementation behaviours. I would suggest, then, that you're writing in the wrong language: C++ programs describe implementation behaviours. It sounds like you'd be happier with a scripting language.

Comment: @Lighness Races in Orbit: `vector.reserve + std::transform` version is good in many cases, but I would use one expression which implicitly hide reserve operation.

Comment: @Khurshid: That's fine, as long as the solution doesn't introduce other factors that may be far unwieldy than a single call to `reserve`. Beware of false economies.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
#include <algorithm> // std::transform
#include <iterator>  // std::back_inserter

....

transform(a.begin(), a.end(), back_inserter(v), F);
```

You may want to call `v.reserve(asize())` first to avoid re-allocations.

Comment: Insidious use of ADL.

Comment: @KerrekSB I was feeling particularly lazy. Friday is the new Sunday.

Comment: @KerrekSB What's ADL? :P

Comment: @herohuyongtao It's what makes the unqualified call `back_inserter(v)` work.

Comment: @Snps: And to `transform`